# What is the best way to do bisecting with subversion?

Tags: svn, git-bisect

I tend to use the bisect command in git extensively. Now I want to do the same in a subversion repository. What is the best way to bisect a subversion repository?

Converting the svn repository to git is not an option because it is a fairly large one and the svn server is dog slow - the conversion would take days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone has written a script for it:
https://metacpan.org/pod/App::SVN::Bisect